# Displaying images in grid with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, grid

I'm creating an application with a store inside of it, so I need a grid view for items' icons with text. iTunes gives a good example of what I need. Any ideas?

http://i55.tinypic.com/16jld3a.png

Answer (score 12):

You could use a `ListBox` that has a `WrapPanel` for its panel type, then use a DataTemplate that uses an `Image` element for the icon and a TextBlock for their caption.

EG:

```
public class MyItemType
{
    public byte[] Icon { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

In window.xaml.cs:

```
public List<MyItemType> MyItems { get; set; }

public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MyItems = new List<MyItemType>();
    MyItemType newItem = new MyItemType();
    newItem.Image = ... load BMP here ...;
    newItem.Title = "FooBar Icon";
    MyItems.Add(newItem);

    this.MainGrid.DataContext = this;
}
```

When loading the icon, refer to [Microsoft's Imaging Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx) since there are a lot of ways to do it.

Then in window.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.Window1"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication"
>

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyItemType}">
       <StackPanel>
           <Image Source="{Binding Path=Icon}"/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
       </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I fleshed out my example a bit more, does that help?

Comment: I've tried to bind this example to my code, but there is a problem "local:MyItemType is not found". Also, can you describe how MyItems.Add works?

Comment: The local: namespace just needs to be declared in the <Window> element: see edit to answer--intellisense will pop-up as soon as you type "xmlns:local=" and you can pick your app's namespace from there. MyItems, in the example, is an instance of List, and the .Add() method just adds a new item to it. Since there's a lot of ways to load images, I linked to Microsoft's Imaging Overview to give you an idea.

Comment: @Eliazar - you'll have to replace that with the type of item you are binding the listbox to.

Comment: No errors now, but the listbox doesn't appear. I've used this converter for bmp 
            MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream();
            Bitmap bitmap1 = new  Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Eliazar\Pictures\1556.bmp");
            bitmap1.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            byte[] byte1 = mstream.ToArray();
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(mstream);
            writer.Write(byte1);