# How to do array for images?

Tags: c#, wpf, arrays, xaml

I have 20 images, they are ball1, ball2, ..., ball20.

Supposedly, I inserted the images using

`Image x:Name="ball1" Source="/Images/ball1.png" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="200"` in .xaml.

Currently, I tried to insert it in this way

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/Images/ball1.png", UriKind.Relative);
ImageSource img = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(uri);
image.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, img);
cv.Children.Add(image);
```

However, I could not use it this way because it does not specify the position that I want to insert it.

I want to avoid doing it through .xaml, how can I do it using array in .cs?

Comment: My only question, which is beside the point of the main issue here, is: why would you want to avoid doing UI work in XAML? That's what it's for...

Comment: Question is about code implementation and belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek Hi, I would wish to do it in .xaml. However, I would not be able to use array to do it.

Comment: @gnat Hi, I could not ask question at Stack Overflow.

Comment: @LiuJiaHui more than likely (since this was migrated here), you weren't banned from StackOverflow but rather caught by the quality filter. Programmers doesn't have quite as strict a filter, but that doesn't mean it is the right place for this question. Working to improve the wording would likely have yet you post on SO.  If there are questions as to why there is a particular problem with posting on SO, it is probably best to ask on meta.stackoverflow rather than posting on another site where the question is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the `Image` objects in XAML and then update the `Source` properties from your code behind or view model if you prefer. For this method, you will need one property per image in your view model or code behind:

```
public string Image1SourcePath
{
    get { return image1SourcePath; }
    set { image1SourcePath = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Image1SourcePath"); }
}
...
public string Image20SourcePath
{
    get { return image20SourcePath; }
    set { image20SourcePath = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Image20SourcePath"); }
}
```

Ensure you implement some form of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image1SourcePath}" Canvas.Left="150" Canvas.Top="200" />
...
<Image Source="{Binding Image20SourcePath}" Canvas.Left="1500" Canvas.Top="200" />
```

Then in your view model or code behind:

```
Image1SourcePath = "/YourApplicationName;component/Images/ball1.png";
...
Image20SourcePath = "/YourApplicationName;component/Images/ball20.png";
```

It's a lot of code, but it allows you to update the `Image.Source` properties from your code behind and set the positions in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling the appropriate static methods on the Canvas class that set the attached properties (Canvas.Left & Canvas.Top).

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/Images/ball1.png", UriKind.Relative);
ImageSource img = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(uri);
image.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, img);
cv.Children.Add(image);

// Position the image on the canvas
Canvas.SetLeft(150);
Canvas.SetTop(200);
```

If you have a list of images to display, you could do something like:

```
        List<Uri> imageUris = new List<Uri>() 
        { 
            new Uri(@"C:\Users\Grant\Pictures\Heron_zoomed.png"),
            new Uri(@"C:\Users\Grant\Pictures\bridge.jpg") 
        };

        int left = 20;
        int top = 10;

        foreach (var uri in imageUris)
        {
            Image image = new Image { Source = new BitmapImage(uri) };
            Canvas.SetLeft(image, left);
            Canvas.SetTop(image, top);
            MainCanvas.Children.Add(image);

            left += 400;
        }
```

The code above assumes you have something like the following in your window xaml and that the file names in the imageUris list exist.

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas">

    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

I have no idea what you are trying to do with these images.  If you just want to display them in a grid you could use one of the WPF collection controls to do this without any code.

One way of doing this is [Displaying images in grid with WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236252/displaying-images-in-grid-with-wpf)

I suspect there are better alternatives but this would be a start.

Comment: Hi, thank you. However, can you show me on how to do it in array?

Comment: @LiuJiaHui Do you have an array of image (bitmap) filenames?

Comment: I do not have it. I will like to know how can I do array for images.

Comment: I have tried it, but it is not working. The image is not displayed it out. The purpose of these images are to be move around the screen.

Comment: The code I posted does work.  The original question related to positioning an image on a canvas.  Have you been able to achieve that?  I recommend you get that working before you move onto trying to get an array of images working.

Comment: Do you know what is wrong when I received this error "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CorrespondingBall.DLL but was not handled in user code" for images[i].Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/images/ball.png"));?

Comment: You are still trying to solve too many problems at once.  1.  Find a bitmap image.  2. Create an Image object using the full path of the image (as in my example).  3.  Add that image to a Canvas. 4.  Set the top/left of the image.   Once you have that going you can move on to arrays, relative image paths etc.